# Prevent symbols from overlapping in qgis

Tags: qgis

I have mutiple of points layers that I want to represent in a map. Because of the reality of the field and some  errors of mapping,  some layers are overlaying so that the printed map is not good and not readable. I'm wondering if there is any possibitilty to manage them so that they would more clear and visible.

[image]

you can clearly see the mess on the map. I would be pleased to get some help from you.

Comment: are your symbols sizes scale-dependent (using map units) ?

Answer (score 4):

First I mistook this was a common [overlapping-features](/questions/tagged/overlapping-features) question... what makes this unique is, that these overlapping points are on different layers.

If we can use [refFunctions](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin:

(1) Open `Layer Properties | Style tab` and highlight `Simple marker`.  Scroll down to `Offset X,Y` and click on `Data defined override` (epsilon icon) and select `Edit`.

(2) In the Expression window, write:

```
CASE 
WHEN count_distinct(geomoverlaps('another_layer', $geometry)) = 0
THEN to_string(rand(-5, 5))  + ',' + to_string(rand(-5, 5)) 
ELSE '0.0,0.0'
END
```

Above example will offset your points by up to 5 mm (if your Offset X,Y unit is set to [Millimeter]) randomly, if they overlaps with those of `another_layer`.

[image]

This approach does have a limitation, as you see, that it works among 2 layers only. Sorry... :(

Comment: Maybe this `another_layer` could be a virtual layer made of the union of the geometries of all other point layers.

Comment: in the latest version of QGIS (>3.8.3), `geomoverlaps` has been renamed as `overlaps`